# Java comparing csv file values

Tags: java, csv, comparison

I'm trying to create a csv file where only 1 team name is shown per row, so when you click the button twice it will only add the team name if its not already there. currently it adds the team "UWE" every single time you press the button. the code for this is below:

```
public void showStats(ActionEvent event){

        try {
            File matchFile = new File("src/sample/matchData.csv");
            File scoreFile = new File("src/sample/scoreData.csv");
            Scanner matchReader = new Scanner(matchFile);
            Scanner scoreReader = new Scanner(scoreFile);
            while (matchReader.hasNextLine()) {
                String data = matchReader.nextLine();
                List<String> matchList = Arrays.asList(data.split(","));
                while (scoreReader.hasNextLine()) {
                    String dataScore = scoreReader.nextLine();
                    List<String> dataScoreList = Arrays.asList(dataScore.split(","));
                    if (dataScoreList.get(0).equals(matchList.get(0))) {
                        //
                    } else {
                        writeExcel("scoreData", matchList.get(0)) ;
                    }
                    System.out.println(dataScoreList);
                }
                System.out.println(matchList);
            }
            matchReader.close();
            scoreReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The csv file "matchData" contains:
UWE,KCC,Jin,Julia,Chris,Ryan,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,5,0

The csv file "scoreData" has one empty line in it

Comment: What does `writeExcel` do?

Comment: Are you keeping track of what teams are already on the spreadsheet by writing to "matchData"? Is this a hard requirement? Even if it is, this is a TERRIBLE way of doing it because of 2 reasons: 1) I/O is much slower than memory and 2) Your lookup will get linearly slower as you put more entries on the file. If it is NOT a hard requirement, store the team in a map. That way, your lookup will be done in constant time.

Comment: And just for the record: unless parsing CSV is some sort of homework, and you are supposed to implement it yourself ... you should not implement it yourself. There are robust libraries that do that for you. Trust me: getting CSV parsing right is much more complicated than you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can first go through your source CSV file and put in a map only the lines that contain unique team key....

```
while (matchReader.hasNextLine()) {
    String data = matchReader.nextLine();
    String[] record = data.split(",", 2);
    Map<String, String> matchList = new TreeMap<>();
    matchList.putIfAbsent(record[0], record[1]); // only unique keys are entered.
}
// TODO write to Excel each entry in the map (you don't need to check for unique keys)
```

Notice that writing to Excel is done after the map is complete. This is the best approach; or at least better than what you showed in your original post. With this approach, you are letting the data structure simplify your process (and no nested loops).

**UPDATE**:

I forgot to mention that `matchList.putIfAbsent(K, V)` works with Java 8 and later. If using Java 7 or older (should upgrade Java ASAP), then you will have to do the following:

```
String value = matchList.get(record[0]);
if (value == null) {
    matchList.put(record[0], record[1]);
}
```

This is because `Map#get(K)` returns `null` is no entry is found OR the map allowed for null values to be entered for a given key. Otherwise, it will return the previous value. The new method introduced in Java 8 does this check automatically.